# Delphi List of Index out of Bounds

Tags: json, google-maps, delphi

I have customers database which I want to check on googlemaps and if the coordenate is found then updates the field latitude.

My code is below but I execute it returns me an error list of index out of bounds. I tried to create a loop but something is not correct.

```
procedure TForm1.btnPegaCoordenadasClick(Sender: TObject);

    var xTemp: TStringList;
    endereco : string;
    tamanho : integer;
    latitude, customer: string;

    begin

      IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
      IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.Mode   := sslmUnassigned;
      IdHTTP1.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;
      xTemp:= TStringList.Create;

      while not qryCustomer.eof do  begin

      endereco:= qryCustomerENDERECOGOOGLE.Value;
      customer := qryCustomerCODE.Value;

      IdHTTP1.Request.Accept := 'text/html, */*';
      IdHTTP1.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; IndyLibrary)';
      IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
      IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects := True;
      xTemp.Text := UTF8Decode(IdHTTP1.Get('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address='+endereco)); 


      // position latitude
      latitude := (xTemp.Strings[63]);



         with ps_UpdatesCustomers do begin
                Parameters.ParamByName('@latitude').Value := latitude;
                Parameters.ParamByName('@customer').Value := customer;
                ps_UpdatesCustomers.ExecProc;
                close;
         end;

       qryCustomers.Next;
     end;
end;
```

Comment: latitude := (xTemp.Strings[63]);
Are you sure google maps *always* returns 64 or more lines with this code?

Comment: it has more lines but I am getting the position of line 63 which is for latitude coordenates.

Comment: It *doesn't* have more lines. The exception you report proves that. You could do some debugging to investigate how many lines it *does* return, but ultimately, all this talk about *lines* is irrelevant because you're dealing with JSON.

Comment: The error message is clear. Did you read it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've hard-coded the index of the line you read:

```
latitude := (xTemp.Strings[63]);
```

I see no reason for you to assume that the 64th line will hold the latitude, nor that there would always *be* at least 64 lines of output. The exception you get indicates that in at least one case, there *aren't* 64 lines of output. (Perhaps the `address_components` array isn't always as long as you expect it to be.)

The URL you provide returns JSON, so what you *should* do is use a JSON parser to process the data. Then read the `results[0].geometry.viewport.southwest.lat` value from it. (The precise syntax for reading that property depends on which JSON library you use.)

Comment: Now I am stuck @Rob. I am using Delphi xe4.

Comment: I'm sorry you're stuck. I thought I answered your question. What are you stuck with?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the length of the `TStringList` variable `xTemp`, before trying to access a specific item.

```
if xTemp.Count >= 64 then
  // Do something with xTemp[63]
else
  raise SomeError
```

---

You should also use a `try/finally` block for the stringlist:

```
 xTemp:= TStringList.Create;
 try
   ...
 finally
   xTemp.Free;
 end;
```

This will avoid memory leaks if something should happen out of the ordinary.